# How to prevent invalid user clicks?

Tags: android, admob

I implemented Admob ads in my Android application. Since I know the strict rules of admob that lead very easily to ban, I would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of clicks that a user can do. If there is a way to do that, what many max clicks number do you recommend?

Comment: Ad mob has its own fraud prevention scripts in place. As long as you don't encourage users to click(by rewarding them) you should be fine.

Comment: But if a malicious user click continually on the banner, he causes my ban from Admob.

Comment: You can't do anything about that, I would advise that you just leave it. Like I said, admob has fraud prevention scrips to stop things like that. It is overkill to worry about things like that. If you just leave your banner at the bottom of the screen you should be fine(that what everyone else does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to limit clicks per user, you could count the number of `onPresentScreen()` callbacks and just stop showing ads if they reach a certain threshold.

However, I agree with the comments on the original post. It's not your job to worry about malicious users who continually click on ads. Just make sure to prevent accidental clicks by not placing your ads very close to user controls, and don't encourage clicks by rewarding users for clicking ads.

Comment: While I agree in principle, google doesn't really care. If they detect the malicious clicks, to them, it's the app developer's responsibility. I've had my account suspended due to invalid click activity.

Comment: I have 2 test devices all of them showing only test ads. Never ever I clicked on my own ad yet i was suspended for 30 days for self clicking. According to the email I can not even appeal? Erm, sorry but what? So no, you should really worry about stuff like this and pray that the almighty google algorithm does not select you...

Answer (score 3):

It is not true to assume admob will know with fairness if it is you provoking fraud clicks through proxy people or a competitor app that is playing dirty. I have a simple traffic incidents app out for a few years now. I live with a browser window open to admob through out the day and just select refresh on it several times a day. Like when taking a break. I have never in two years seen the dollar amount go down upon selecting refresh. Not once.

Now I have other apps in the app store that are word games with more serious competitors than the humble old traffic incidents app. Almost every other day on word games I now refresh the admob page and spot it actually going down in estimated value rather than up. It happens once or twice every two days. This means for the first time, admob is now reversing clicks. Both the traffic app and the word game get equivalent usage and have the ad banner at the bottom on both. In fact it is probably more likely to accidentally click an ad with the traffic app than the word game.

I believe this is evidence I have caught the attention of a competitor and they are attempting to ban my admob account. It to easy to do and now I am on someone's radar in this new arena of word games.

So at the end of the day, anyone can easily frame another admob user of click fraud. It depends upon your app's genre and the competitive climate of that genre, and second, the integrity of your competitors in that genre.

Comment: What, I have been facing these days? Admob has limited my ad serving since today morning. I didn't do any invalid activity with my admob account. What can I do?